# How can I insert the value of filename in a new column in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to combine multiple csv files, while combining I want to add the file name of each csv files into a column.

I am trying using glob or pandas, but it seems not working.

```py
files = glob.glob('fp')
    print (files)
    x1 = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('fp').assign(New=os.path.basename('fp')) for 'fp' in files])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, is necessary change `'fp'` to `fp` and also if necessary remove expension add `.split('.')[0]`:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp).assign(New=os.path.basename(fp).split('.')[0]) for fp in files]

x1 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```